# Convergence of Conjugate Gradient Method

Tags: numerics

Can anyone help me prove that, if the residual $r_0 = b-Au_0$ can be written as a linear combination of $k$ eigenvectors of $A$, then the CG method will converge to a solution $x^{*}= A^{-1}b$ in at most k steps. With $N=I_n$ and $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You know this is true if $k=n$? Then show that the iteration remains in the invariant subspace spanned by the $k$ eigenvectors.

Comment: The CG method converges within at most $n$ iterations so for $k=n$ , this is true. what do you mean with "the iteration remains in the invariant subspace"? In each iteration the algorithm chooses an orthogonal direction leaving the subspace? Sorry, I am so lost.